# Can't pop into command mode with escape key in Jupyter Notebook, but can in Jupyter Lab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I recently reinstalled conda, jupyter etc and am now encountering an irritating bug.

I often hit `esc` to transition from edit mode to command mode. When I hit `esc` in my current install, my cursor jumps out of the cell and aligns with the blue bar that normally signifies I'm in command mode. Subsequent use of the up/down arrow keys just moves that cursor around, but doesn't move the cell selection.

If I hit the JupyterLab popout button (top right of screengrab below), this issue is resolved and `esc` functions as normal. I find jupyterlab annoying, so would prefer to be able to use notebooks.

I've included a screengrab of the jupyter versions that I currently have installed. I'm running both notebooks and Jlab in the July 2022 version of Chrome for Ubuntu (which is the latest one available).

[image]
[image]